Warp terminal emulator not displaying starship prompt colors correctly
I have recently moved from iTerm2 to Warp. However, when I set up starship the colors of the nerd font icons that make up the prompt "blend" into each other. This doesn't happen on iTerm.
(I'm using Hack Nerd Font Mono)
The warp window
iTerm2 (expected result)
In Warp the colors seem to overlay on top of each other and become darker on the overlap.
My starship.toml is as follows.
"$schema" = 'https://starship.rs/config-schema.json'

format = """
[](surface0)\
$os\
[](bg:peach fg:surface0)\
$directory\
[](fg:peach bg:green)\
$git_branch\
$git_status\
[](fg:green bg:teal)\
$c\
$rust\
$golang\
$nodejs\
$php\
$java\
$kotlin\
$haskell\
$python\
[](fg:teal bg:blue)\
$docker_context\
[](fg:blue bg:pink)\
$time\
[ ](fg:pink)\
$line_break$character"""

palette = 'catppuccin_mocha'

[palettes.catppuccin_mocha]
rosewater = "#f5e0dc"
flamingo = "#f2cdcd"
pink = "#f5c2e7"
orange = "#cba6f7"
red = "#f38ba8"
maroon = "#eba0ac"
peach = "#fab387"
yellow = "#f9e2af"
green = "#a6e3a1"
teal = "#94e2d5"
sky = "#89dceb"
sapphire = "#74c7ec"
blue = "#89b4fa"
lavender = "#b4befe"
text = "#cdd6f4"
subtext1 = "#bac2de"
subtext0 = "#a6adc8"
overlay2 = "#9399b2"
overlay1 = "#7f849c"
overlay0 = "#6c7086"
surface2 = "#585b70"
surface1 = "#45475a"
surface0 = "#313244"
base = "#1e1e2e"
mantle = "#181825"
crust = "#11111b"

[os]
disabled = false
style = "bg:surface0 fg:text"

[os.symbols]
Windows = ""
Ubuntu = ""
SUSE = ""
Raspbian = ""
Mint = ""
Macos = ""
Manjaro = ""
Linux = ""
Gentoo = ""
Fedora = ""
Alpine = ""
Amazon = ""
Android = ""
Arch = ""
Artix = ""
CentOS = ""
Debian = ""
Redhat = ""
RedHatEnterprise = ""

[username]
show_always = true
style_user = "bg:surface0 fg:text"
style_root = "bg:surface0 fg:text"
format = '[ $user ]($style)'

[directory]
style = "fg:mantle bg:peach"
format = "[ $path ]($style)"
truncation_length = 3
truncation_symbol = "…/"

[directory.substitutions]
"Documents" = " "
"Downloads" = " "
"Music" = " "
"Pictures" = " "
"Developer" = " "

[git_branch]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol $branch ](fg:base bg:green)]($style)'

[git_status]
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[($all_status$ahead_behind )](fg:base bg:green)]($style)'

[nodejs]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[c]
symbol = " "
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[rust]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[golang]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[php]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[java]
symbol = " "
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[kotlin]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[haskell]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[python]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:teal"
format = '[[ $symbol( $version) ](fg:base bg:teal)]($style)'

[docker_context]
symbol = ""
style = "bg:mantle"
format = '[[ $symbol( $context) ](fg:#83a598 bg:color_bg3)]($style)'

[time]
disabled = false
time_format = "%R"
style = "bg:peach"
format = '[[  $time ](fg:mantle bg:pink)]($style)'

[line_break]
disabled = false

[character]
disabled = false
success_symbol = '[](bold fg:green)'
error_symbol = '[](bold fg:red)'
vimcmd_symbol = '[](bold fg:creen)'
vimcmd_replace_one_symbol = '[](bold fg:purple)'
vimcmd_replace_symbol = '[](bold fg:purple)'
vimcmd_visual_symbol = '[](bold fg:lavender)'

